# I want to delete records older than 6 years plus current financial year

Tags: sql, delete-row

I am going with this. But not sure how to include current financial year in it.

```
DELETE FROM myTable 
WHERE MyColumn <= DATEADD(MONTH, -60, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Please provide (1) sample data.  (2) desired results.  (3) An appropriate database tag.  (4) A definition of what you mean by "current financial year" and "older then 6 years plus".

Comment: What DBMS?  SQL Server?  Date functions vary widely by DBMS.

Comment: Sample Data: my table contains user details like id, name, updateddate. Desired Result: want to delete records older than (6 years + current financial year). current financial year as of now will include dates from 1st April, 2019 current date. the dates for current financial year will change. SQLServer2014

Answer (score 0):

`Delete * from table where year(dateColumn) <= @year` should do it for you.